# unable to increment static vaue in PHP

Tags: php, session

I am trying to print score automatically, if the question is correct it should increment the score.  I tried this function:

```
function checkscore ()
{
    static $score = 0;
    if ($_SESSION['result']  == "Correct")
       $score++;
    return $score;
}
```

this function returns **1** if the question is correct or **0** if the question is wrong. But $score does not increment in any case. How can I make increment the $score variable?

Comment: You need to pass the variable as the argument of function.

Comment: srry im very new php....can u plz explain me more clearly if u dont mind

Comment: variable exists only when request exists. Each new request will create new variable. And after execution all variables will be terminated. Static variable can be incremented only due request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your code but I imaging you are expecting the static variable to remain in existance over multiple calls to this script.

That is not how static works!

If you use it like this:

```
function checkscore ()
{
    static $score = 0;
    if ($_SESSION['result']  == "Correct")
       $score ++;
    return $score;
} 

echo checkscore () . '<br>';
echo checkscore () . '<br>';
echo checkscore () . '<br>';
```

You will get the result:

```
1
2
3
```

But if you are calling the script from a form where the user answers ONE question and the form is submitted to this script `static` will not work as you expect. The static variable will be initialised to zero on each call to the script.

If you want to remember the value of $score across multiple calls to the script you will have to save it in the $_SESSION something like this

```
function checkscore ()
{
    $score = isset($_SESSION['score']) ? $_SESSION['score'] : 0;
    if ($_SESSION['result']  == "Correct")
       $score ++;
       $_SESSION['score'] = $score;
    return $score;
}
```

Comment: yup thnx a lot its working fine bu there is a problem still till question its working fine but after question3 its printing score 1 and after question 4 its showing 3....till question 3 its working properly...

Answer (score 2):

Do not init $score variable, like this:

```
function checkscore ()
{
    static $score; // Here without initialization
    if (is_null($score)) {
        $score = 0;
    }

    if ($_SESSION['result']  == "Correct") {
        $score++;
    }

    return $score;
}

$_SESSION['result'] = 'Correct';
checkscore();  // 1
checkscore();  // 2
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the variable as the argument of function.Try like this

```
function checkscore ($score){
  if ($_SESSION['result']  == "Correct")
     $score ++;
return $score;
}

//Function call example;
checkscore (1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this also, pass by refrence

```
function checkscore (&$score){
  if ($_SESSION['result']  == "Correct"){
     $score ++;
      return 'correct';
  }else{
     return 'wrong';
  }

//Function call example;
$score = 1;
checkscore ($score);
echo $score;
```

In this way you will return two values from a function one will say correct or wrong and reference variable will update score as well.

Answer (score 0):

static variable gets initialized only once even re-initialization will not effect value of variable, A static variable exists only in a local function scope, but it does not lose its value when program execution leaves this scope.

```
function checkscore ()
{
   static $score = 0;
   if ($_SESSION['result']  == "Correct")
      $score++;
   return $score;
}
```

Nothing wrong with your code check wether you may be doing it wrong on the calling section or handling return value.